# Is there any research on episodic-like memory in reptiles?

Tags: brain, herpetology, memory, cognition

I've been studying the area of episodic-like memory in non-human animals and our old reptile cousins seem to be really underrepresented (or not represented at all). Is there any research that I am missing? Anything that would point to reptiles remembering what, where and when of an event? The only papers I could find were related to spatial memory (what & where), like this:

[Rapid learning of a spatial memory task in a lacertid lizard (Podarcis liolepis)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335935643_Rapid_learning_of_a_spatial_memory_task_in_a_lacertid_lizard_Podarcis_liolepis) - by Enrique Font

Also here: @ https://doi.org/10.1016/j.beproc.2019.103963

Comment: Have you tried google scholar? if you go trough the papers that cited the one you mention you will get some related research.